# Mysql MariaDB replication broken

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-replication, mariadb

I have a primary DB and two replicates. replicate1 became corrupted
when the linux server was rebooted without stopping mysqld. I want to load
replicate1 with a dump I've taken from replicate2 with the command

mysqldump --master-data --single-transaction --all-databases  --compress > full_dumpfle.sql

dump was started after replication on replicate12 was stopped with

stop slave;

as soon as the dump was initiated, I restarted replication on replicate2 with

start slave;

dump file is 50G in size.

I copied the my.cnf file from replicate4 to replicate1, keeping the server-id 
from replicate1's previous my.cnf file, along with the master_user and master_password
lines.

I load the DB with

mysql < full_dumpfile.sql

I find that the load exhausts the disk, which was sufficient for replicate1
before the unfortunate reboot. I've even added 100G of disk and the load threatens
to exhaust that as well.

I truncated the slow_log table which was an enormous 128G
and dropped the main database which was another 56G, after one failed load
that nearly exhausted the available disk, about 245G is free when I begin the 
second load.

All I want to do is return replicate1 to service as a replicate of the master.
Obviously the method I'm using is not working. Can anyone give me directions
on how to load the dump correctly? Not wedded to the dump, can take another.
Can even initiate replication on replicate1 from scratch, if need be, but would
rather not load the master, if I can help it.

All of this takes place on our private cloud, so keeping the load down is advisable.

All of this is on ubuntu10.04LTS and MaridDB.

Server version: 5.2.12-MariaDB-mariadb115~lucid-log

Any constructive advice would be appreciated.

Raul

Answer (score 0):

I've good experiences with Percona XtraBackup. See the "[How to setup a slave for replication in 6 simple steps with Xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html)" recipe.